# PowerShell SQL Server Datatable extra "row"

Tags: powershell

In PowerShell I have this function:
function RunSQLServerQuery
{
    param (
        [string]$server = “.”,
        [string]$instance = $(throw “Database Name is Required”),
        [string]$query,
        $parameters=@{}
    )

```
$connection = new-object system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection( `
    “Data Source=$server;Initial Catalog=$instance;Integrated Security=TRUE;”);
$connection.Open
$cmd=new-object system.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($query,$connection)
foreach($p in $parameters.Keys)
{
    [Void] $cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@$p",$parameters[$p])
}
$dt=New-Object system.Data.DataSet
$da=New-Object system.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter($cmd)
$da.fill($dt) | Out-Null

return $dt.Tables[0]
```

}

When I call it like this:
$MyTest = "select GetDate()"
$rows = RunSQLServerQuery "servername" "master" $MyTest @{}
$rows

I get the following results:
MemberType          : Method
OverloadDefinitions : {System.Void Open()}
TypeNameOfValue     : System.Management.Automation.PSMethod
Value               : System.Void Open()
Name                : Open
IsInstance          : True

Column1 : 7/19/2011 2:14:13 PM

When I inspect the value of $dt.Tables[0] before exiting the function the value is as expected:
Column1                                                                                              -------
7/19/2011 2:16:13 PM

I can't figure out why this is. I have tried switching the return to *return ,$dt.Tables[0]*, but that was to no avail. I can't figure out why PowerShell is adding this text when return back from the function. There has to be something easy that I am missing.

Boezo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the line `$connection.open`

It should read `[void]$connection.open()`

You're getting the open method as part of your output instead of invoking it.

Comment: Thanks That did it! I knew it was something simple that I couldn't see :)